# Can a limit be thought of as an operation that makes a discontinuous function continuous, and evaluates it?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here are some examples. If you take the limit of $x^2/x$ as it approaches $0$, you get $0$, because the limit just plugs in the hole of the graph to make $x$ and evaluates it for $x=0$. Another example would be $|x|/x$. When you make the function continuous, you get a vertical bar of infinite values at $x=0$, so since there is no one value, this limit is undefined.

Comment: I suppose you could think of it as: The limit tells you how to extend the definition of a function, to ensure that you obtain a continuous function. (One complication of this mindset is that you can have one-sided limits.)

Comment: Well the notion of a continuous function is built up using limits. So i think the proposal is circular.

Answer (score 1):

A general statement is as follows.

If you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{a\}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L,
$$
then the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x),&x\ne a\\
L,&x=a
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g$ is continuous at $x=a$.